# Force ViewPager to load one fragment (on demand)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

`ViewPager` loads at least two fragments in memory. I'm trying to reach the best solution to load only one fragment in memory.

I know this topic has been opened before, but I'm trying to reach the best solution.

I tried creating a custom `ViewPager` by editing the `DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES` to `0`.

Comment: Can you add the othera solutions and what you have done so far? Please

Comment: @cutiko I have tried editing the DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES but i dont like the solution, and im not sure of setuservisible solution

Comment: If you don't want the inherent (and rather necessary) behavior of `ViewPager`, don't use a `ViewPager`. You can certainly handle the `FragmentTransaction`s yourself.